# Getting "response code 500" in jmeter when running the list of APIs . How to increase the time to get variable value from the previous reponse

Tags: jmeter

Getting "response code 500" in jmeter when running the list of APIs (with two slaves for 250 users with ramp up period-2), this is due to not able to fetch the variable value from the previous request's response. I have already set the 'constant timer'. Please suggest what other things i can take care to overcome if have to increase the time to get the response

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Using a different sample sender](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode) chapter of the [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) manual. By default JMeter uses **StrippedBatch** mode to send results from remote slaves to the master, these "Stripped" modes remove response data from the samplers to if you have postprocessors for doing correlation - they will fail:

1. > **StrippedBatch**
   >   remove responseData from successful samples, and use Batch sender to send them.
2. > Stripped mode family strips **responseData** so this means that some Elements that rely on the previous **responseData** being available will not work.

You can add the next line to *user.properties* file on your JMeter instances:

```
mode=Standard
```

Or amend JMeter startup line to set the property via -J command-line argument like

```
jmeter -Jmode=Standard -s -j jmeter.log
```

See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter tuning using properties.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. When tried running in non-gui mode by adding -Jmode=Standard as below unable to get response (3 ec2 instances - 1 master and 2 slaves hitting APIs)     sudo docker exec -i master /bin/bash -c "/jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter -n -t /home/$jmx -Jmode=Standard -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$master -Dclient.rmi.localport=60000 -R$slave_1,$slave_2 -j jmeter.log -l result.csv"